# Why is getCountFromServer throwing an error?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Simple bit of code:

```
import { getCountFromServer, getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const db = getFirestore(env.CONFIG);

const q = query(collection(db, "entries"));
const snapshot = await getCountFromServer(q);
snapshot.data().count;
```

Throws the following error:

> Index.esm2017.js:18650 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_userDataWriter')
> at data (index.esm2017.js:18650:1)

Odd because as far as I can tell this is correct usage. The call is being made from the web client. Worth noting I am using the Firestore emulator to make this call.

Bug?

Firebase: 9.21.0

Node: 19.7.0

Typescript CRA (`react-scripts`): 5.0.1

Edit: Tested this without the emulator, getting the same error.

Comment: Where is `db` coming from? Can you add all imports in your code where it is exported from?

Comment: Updated example

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is passed from env.CONFIG but you have to initialize firebase client first with the configuration object.

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
    FIREBASE_CONFIGURATION

};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


// Initialize Cloud Firestore and get a reference to the service
const db = getFirestore(app);

const q = query(collection(db, "entries"));
const snapshot = await getCountFromServer(q);
snapshot.data().count;
```

Comment: I initialize the env fine. Other Firebase functionality (firestore reads and writes etc.) works fine. `getCountFromServer` throws an error nonetheless.